# Convert a regular expression in a string to a regexp object in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I take a regular expression as an input from the user and match values against that regex. 
But, the problem i have is that the input i receive is a string. 
e.g. `"/abc|def/i"`
And i am not able to convert it to a regex object.
If it try `Regexp.new(string)`
it escapes all the characters so i get something like `/\/abc|def\/i/`

I was able to capture the part between the forward slashes using another regex and build a regexp object using it. For the above example, i capture `"abc|def"` and when i do `Regexp.new("abc|def")` i get `/abc|def/` which is what i wanted but i need a way to also add the regexp options(e.g. 'i' in the above example) in the string to the ruby regexp object.

How can i achieve this ???

Also, there must be a easier way to achieve all of this. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Regexp.new` is only escaping the "delimiters" (`/`) and modifiers (`i`). Why not let the user drop the delimiters and enter any modifiers separately? See how they solved it at http://rubular.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might look into using the [to_regexp gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/to_regexp); it doesn't use `eval` and it will allow you to do this:

```
 "/(abc|def)/i".to_regexp
 # => /(abc|def)/i
```

Source at https://github.com/seamusabshere/to_regexp

Answer (score 6):

Here's a quick way to do it
`/#{my_string_pattern}/`

No magic required

Comment: @Sohan if you add \b forward slash "\" get encoded to ascii char,any suggestion  ??

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun... enjoy:

```
class Regexp
  def self.parse(s)
    optmap = {
      "i" => Regexp::IGNORECASE,
      "x" => Regexp::EXTENDED,
      "m" => Regexp::MULTILINE
    }

    match = s.match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)/) or raise "Invalid regexp string"
    pat = match.captures[0]
    opt_str = match.captures[1]
    opts = opt_str.split(//).map { |c| optmap[c] }.reduce { |x, n| x | n }
    Regexp.new(pat, opts)
  end
end

# because you aren't hacking Ruby until you've added a method to String...
class String
  def to_regex
    Regexp.parse(self)
  end
end
```

It works, too!

Comment: Looks like it would require options or it would fail.  Otherwise, I like the way you've done it.

Comment: Nope. Works fine without options. The capture group is just an empty string, in that case.

Comment: You are right, thanks.  I'll read code more carefully in the future.

Comment: missing `p` in `Regex.parse(self)`

Comment: Thanks... String::to_regex was just tacked on here in the text area :)

Answer (score 0):

As you've suggested, I think that your method might be a way to handle it.  You can clean it up a little by doing something like this...

```
class String
  def to_regexp(case_insensitive = false)
    str = self[\/(.*)\/,1]
    Regexp.new(str, case_insensitive)
  end
end
```

This is just one way to clean it up and make the functionality inherent to Strings so you don't have to worry about it.